# Scene2d adding actors on top of table

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx, scene2d

I have a scrollable table that contains all the main functions of my menu, buttons, heading etc. Now I want a "hud" on top of this that does not scroll, like in facebook messenger. with tabs for "friends" and "settings" etc. The problem is when I try to add something else to the stage after the table the positioning is off, I've tried adding another Stage but then the input doesnt work, and I've tried adding another table but then the positioning is off (but the input works)

Current code:

```
        //table.top();
        table.add(heading).colspan(2);
        table.getCell(heading).spaceBottom(100);
        table.row();
        table.add(buttonPlay).colspan(2);
        table.getCell(buttonPlay).spaceBottom(100);
        table.row();
        table.add(buttonExit).colspan(2);
        table.getCell(buttonExit).spaceBottom(1000); //large spacing to test so scrolling works fine
        table.row();
        table.add(buttonFriends);
        table.add(buttonSettings);
        hudTable.add(buttonHud);
        hudTable.debug();
        stage.addActor(container);
        stage.addActor(hudTable);
```

Gives a result that looks like this:

[image]

All this works, the main table scrolls, the HUD stays still while I scroll and the input works, but the positioning is off and I can't figure out how to fix this so the HUD is on top. Any ideas? Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Have you tried using inputMultiplexer when you add two stages to process inputs from both the stage.
Read here http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=11916

Comment: I have not, thank you! @Sneh Maybe Im dumb but I don't find anything about inputMultiplexer in that link.

Comment: Let me know if it fixes your problem.

Comment: @Sneh That link doesnt mention inputMultiplexer, Im not sure what you mean. It is true that the thread discussess the same issue kind of, but there is no real solution offered? Or am I missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments you can use `InputMultiplexer` class to process multiple stages.

Inside `InputMultiplexer` there is a method called `addProcessor()` which takes any object which implements `InputProcessor` and allow your inputs to be processed.

The stage class already implements `InputProcessor` see **Javadocs** http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.html

So let us say you have two stages

```
Stage stage1 = new Stage();
Stage stage2 = new Stage();
```

Now all you have to do is

```
InputMultiplexer multiPlexer = new InputMultiplexer();
multiPlexer.addProcessor(stage1);
multiPlexer.addProcessor(stage2);
```

**EDIT**

Just for reference this is how I do it using 1 stage

```
public class BattleScreen extends Table {
    private BattleActionScreen battleActionScreen;
    private BattlePokemonScreen battlePokemonScreen;
}
```

Both the private members of this table are also tables. 
In my game I add `BattleScreen` inside the stage.

**EDIT**
Here is the image to demonstrate the same
[image: Battle Screen Image]

Comment: Thanks you, will try this when I get home and let you know! :)

Comment: No worries, I had faced similar problems earlier though I didn't use multiple stages but I made multiple tables and added them in stage and positioned them.

Comment: How did you do that? I've tried `hudTable.setPosition(0, 0);` But this gives the same result as in the image. No idea why.

Comment: Unfortunately the multiPlexer does not work, input for the hud does not work using that method it seems like. Could u maybe exaplin how u solved it using 2 tables?

Comment: How I have done is I have a Stage and I just add one Table in it. But that 1 table is made up of multiple tables.
So for the HUD, I have different Table, For Button Box I have a different table which contains all the Buttons. I do extend Table class in my GUI classes and that way it is much easier to work with them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82319/discussion-between-ique-and-sneh).